# Comparing Embryonic stem cell and hepatic stem cell

Tags: development, stem-cells

So, currently, I want to compare transcriptome data for liver cell development. I found 2 data sets which start from stem cell, hepatoblast, and then adult cell. The first data set use hepatic stem cell and the second data set use embryonic stem cell. I am trying to map the difference in the gene expression during cell development, so it is important to make sure the state of the cell is same. My question is, is this stem cell comparable and can be grouped as 1 category? If hepatic stem cell and embryonic stem cell is different, is there something in common that probably can be used as basis of my analysis?